# Lock DbContext for operation completion in EF6

Tags: entity-framework-6, task-parallel-library

I have some code in my business logic layer which consume some repositories which in turn use a DbContext (in the data layer). Most of the code is async. At some point in my business logic, I call several async method of the repositories at once (`Task.WhenAll...)`)
And I ran into an error `A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed`

My point of view is, the business logic should not care/be aware on how the repositories do their job, so it should be able to use parallelism on async Task if "it pleases so".

So I would like to be able to lock in an async/await friendly way the critical moment where `A second operation` should wait until the `previous asynchronous operation` complete.

How can this be done?

Current work-arround: forget **Task.WhenAll** use **await** like TPL don't even exist

```
        var postsResult = await _IUserLogic.GetActivePostsAsync();
        var usersResult = await _IUserLogic.SearchUsersWithPostAsync(viewModel.Name, viewModel.PostId);
```

Code To-be

```
        var postsTask = _IUserLogic.GetActivePostsAsync();
        var usersTask = _IUserLogic.SearchUsersWithPostAsync(viewModel.Name, viewModel.PostId);
        await Ask.WhenAll(postsTask , usersTask );
        var postsResult = postsTask.Result;
        var usersResult = usersTask.Result;
```

Comment: A `DbContext` is not a thread safe object. You need a separate instance per request. One easy approach is to inject the conn string into your repo and produce your context per request with that. Locking is not going to be your answer here as that is simply another way of forcing sequential processing of the requests, same as awaiting each in turn.

Comment: using several DbContext to read data would work (and bleed the memory). But as soon as it would involve updating data, they might interfere (runtime exception). So it's not a viable solution for me. Locking would indeed make the whole think actually be sequential, but my Business Logic would not have to deal with it (even if await is simple to use, it doesn't mean it should appear everywhere). If tomorrow I change my data source to something which would support parallel read (ADO.Net?), my business logic would take advantage of it without a whole re factorization.

Comment: If you really want an async lock you can use a [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netframework-4.7.1)

Comment: But where to use it then?

Comment: You use a lock, async or not, around a shared resource. Your shared resource is the `DbContext` and that is used within your repo. So you can either setup the semaphore in your repo or even decorate it with a `LockingRepo<T>`, really whatever works best in your project.

Answer (score 2):

Each thread needs its own DbContext because DbContext is not thread safe.  However, there are a few work-arounds here.

1. Each repository gets their own, new DbContext.  That way, each has their own instance on their own thread.  If you need this to be a single transaction, you can use Transaction Scope (newest version allows async calls).
2. The business layer passes the dbcontext into each repository and will call save changes once at the end.  Each repository simply adds their data to the DbSets and you have a single call at the end.
3. (Worst) Override SaveChanges on DbContext in your instance and create your own lock() so all go through there.  However, his pretty much defeats the purpose of Task.WhenAll since you can only save one at a time, anyway.
4. Do what you did and call them individually.